# Fine tune without using pointers

Tags: c++

** To print repeated elements from an user defined array

```
//print repeated elements from an array

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
  {
   int p,n;

   cout<<"enter no. of elements in array: "<<endl;
   cin>>n;
   int a[n],b[n];
   int z=0;
   cout<<"enter elements of array:"<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(int k=j;k<=n;k++)
        {
            if(j==k)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(a[j]==a[k])
            {
                b[z]=a[j];
                ++z;
                a[k]=a[k+1];        //deleting the array element which repeats
                a[n-1]=0;           //settng last element as 0
                --n;                //reducing the size of array
                break;
            }
            int d=z;
            if(b[j]==b[k])
            {
                b[j]=b[j+1];
                b[n-1]=0;
                n--;
            }
        }
    }
    if(z==0)
    {
        cout<<"No Elemnts in the array is repeated"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"repeated elements are: "<<endl;
        for(p=0;p<z;p++)
            {
                cout<<b[p]<<" ";
            }
    }

return 0;
}
```

How to fine tune this program so as it displays correct output? When we enter 3 similar elements it repeats itself twice and also has problem reading the last element.
Thanks

Comment: When you step through the program in a debugger, at what point does the actual state of the program differ from the state you expect it to have?

Comment: Correctness is not really my understanding of `fine-tune`.

Comment: If u vary no. of times the digits are repeated the output varies accordingly, i.e. if u input more than 3 times a single digit than in display it displays more than 2 times or so where I want it to display once. Also if u vary the position of the digits which are repeated especially the first and last element of the array the output varies. This is the exact nature of the two problems I am facing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Attach a debugger to the program and step through it, statement by statement, observing the state of the program at each statement.  Determine what you expect the state to be at that point, and observe whether the actual state matches what you expect.  This will help you to find where the bug lies.  Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Than tell me does there look like any fault in the concept of the program or maybe better way to approach this program?

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your algorithm. Something like that should work:

```
  std::vector<int> a;

  /* fill a */

  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  std::vector<int> unique_elements;
  std::unique_copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(unique_elements));

  std::vector<int> b;
  std::copy_if(unique_elements.begin(), unique_elements.end(), std::back_inserter(b), [&](int n)
  {
    return std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), n) >= 2;
  });
```

Comment: `a` is sorted, so in the `copy_if` predicate, instead of the linear complexity `count` you can use `equal_range` and `distance`, for logarithmic complexity:  `auto const range(std::equal_range(begin(a), end(a), n)); return std::distance(range.first, range.second) >= 2;`